# PHP Mail Sending a dynamic PHP Contents

Tags: php, sendmail, php-include

I'm Creating a weekly Updates to my clients, and I want to include the latest (News, Articles, Photos) in this mail. So I created "webmail.php" page that's been created **Dynamically** using MySql, contains all my updates I want to send to my clients, with heavy css and html contents.
I'm using this PHP code in my script

```
ob_start();
include ('webmail.php');
$content = ob_get_clean();
$message = $content;
mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

The problem is I'm facing (500 Internal Server Error). I'm sure that my webmail.php contains no errors and this problem happens because this page has been created Dynamically.
Any Idea to solve this problem?. Thanks

Comment: if your php had no errors, then you wouldn't be getting a 500. Check your webserver's error log for more details. What you've posted is semantically correct PHP, and is absolutely useless for debugging, because that code snippet has NOTHING wrong with it. Whatever the bug is, it's inside webmail.php, which you haven't shown at all

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing a point there... If `webmail.php` is dynamically generated (which means it actually **contains** your information), then you can read its contents using :

```
$news = file_get_contents("webmail.php");
```

and just send `$news` as your email body. However, if `webmail.php` actually generates the content (which means it **produces** it when passed to the PHP interpretor), then maybe you should consider using a function in this file instead :

**webmail.php**

```
function latest_news(){
    // Gets news from database, put them into $news.
    return $news;
}
```

Then, on your first page (sending the email) :

```
include_once("webmail.php"); // Get the function.
mail("recipient@address.tld", "Our latest news", latest_news());
```